# Sigma js events

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

In sigma js, is there a way that I can reference the node that was clicked during the event? I have a graph made up of nodes of different colors which I would like to change upon being clicked. I have a clickNode event bound to a function, but in that function I am having trouble getting the reference to the node that is being clicked.

There is the graph.nodes('id') method which returns a node per the given id passed as a parameter, and this works fine when I know what the id is, but how can I get a reference to the node when the node is clicked so that I can use that node and change its properties(such as color, label, etc.)? Below is a segment of my code.

```
    sigma sigmaInst = new sigma('container');

    function popFieldsClickNode()
    {    
        var n = ****I need n to hold a reference to the clicked node****
        n.color = '#0066ff';    
        n.label = 'selected';

        sigmaInst.refresh();
    }
    sigmaInst.bind('clickNode', popFieldsClickNode);
```

If you know how to do this, or if you have a better way of doing this please give me some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/events.html#L116-L118

Your `popFieldsClickNode` should have an argument corresponding to the data event in wich you should have your node data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your function event argument so you will be able get clicked node data.
It will look like this.

```
function popFieldsClickNode(event){    
    var n = event.data;
    console.log(n);//do your stuff here

    sigmaInst.refresh();
}
```